# Is there a way to make image and text alternate between rows?

Tags: display-suite

In Drupal theme, the content would have image and title which will have image on left and text on right in Display Suite under view in each row.

The client wants:
In first row, the image will be on left and text will be right. Next row, text on left and image on right.

Is there a module that can alternate between rows? Or display suite can do that?

Thanks

Comment: This is more of a CSS issue than anything else. Views provide striping in its format settings (odd/even) which you can leverage.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom module as follows:

In sites/all/modules create a directory: ds_odd_even

Add a file ds_odd_even.info under that directory.
Add the following text in that file:

```
name = "Display Suite Odd Even Output"
description = "Display Suite Odd Even Output."
core = "7.x"
```

Add a file ds_odd_even.module under same directory.
Add the following text to that file:

```
<?php

function ds_views_row_adv_past_client($entity, $view_mode, $load_comments) {
  static $i = 0;
  $custom_view_mode = ($i++ % 2) == 1 ? 'left_client' : 'right_client';
  return render(node_view($entity, $custom_view_mode));
}
```

Install the module as usual. Note the function name above. It is based on the pattern: ds_views_row_adv_YOUR_VIEW_MACHINE_NAME. This is the view name from the admin/structure/views UI page, not the display name from the right hand advanced column on a view. Hence the view that this is based on has a machine name of past_client. If you add more pages and blocks to this view, the view's machine name still stays the same. Each page or block will get a display name in addition. IT IS NOT THE DISPLAY NAME that you add to the function.

Create two view modes in Display Suite.
1. left_client
2. right_client

Add two column layout to both, with alternating image and body placement.

In your view (machine name past_client) set to show Display Suite as format, and in setting select under Advanced View Mode 'Use the advanced view mode selector'.

Clear your cache for good measure. And that is it.

There is no way I see to differentiate on different displays on the same view, unfortunately. You may explore CSS as an alternative, and use the nth-child() selector to alternatively float the display suite regions left or right (make sure you have greater specificity in the cascade or use !important)

Comment: @Reynolds - wa thanks for the help but it is over my head. I will study your code example. thanks

Comment: @JReynolds - tried your example and fiddle but still it does not work. hmm

Comment: Create two new View modes using Display Suite. One for image left, other for image right. Then send me the machine names of those two view modes, as well as the machine name for the View you are using and I will assist.

Comment: @JReynolds - many thanks. I created two new view modes in DS - right_client and left_client (both have images and title). The views' machine name is past_client_pane and current_client_pane. I assume that one template can be reused for both views. Thanks again for your help

Comment: Revised my answer

Comment: @JReynolds -- I got tons of errors but it says: Strict warning: Only variables should be passed by reference in ds_views_row_adv_clients() (line 6) i am guessing that right_client or left_client are not right?

Answer (score 0):

In view - go to Display setting - you will see "Alternating view mode"

Check two checkboxes: 
1. Use the changing view mode selector
2. Use this configuration on every page. Otherwise the default view mode is used as soon you browse away from the first page of this view.

Then you need to set view mode for each item.

That's it.

Comment: This works very well but only if the view has less than 10 nodes.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no such setting in Drupal by default, but there's a module for it called Views Parity Row:
https://www.drupal.org/project/views_parity_row